# Python 2.7 - file threading.py seems not work- ImportError: cannot import name time

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7

I have macOS Sierra, using python 2.7 for a homework.
I have an import problem as followed :

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/networkx/release.py", line 43, in <module>
import time
File "/Users/chen/Desktop/minesparis/JE/Chronomap/scripts/time.py", line 3, in <module>
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 122, in <module>
from matplotlib.cbook import is_string_like, mplDeprecation, dedent, get_label
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook.py", line 33, in <module>
  import numpy as np
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 201, in <module>
  from . import random
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/random/__init__.py", line 99, in <module>
  from .mtrand import *
File "mtrand.pyx", line 151, in init mtrand (numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.c:37668)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/dummy_threading.py", line 45, in <module>
  import threading
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 15, in <module>
  from time import time as _time, sleep as _sleep
  ImportError: cannot import name time
```

I open the script threading.py and try to run it and everything seems working.
When I write

```
 from time import time as _time, sleep as _sleep
```

on my console, the import works.
so I don't know what is the problem and how can I solve it..

Thank you very much!
Mia

Comment: In short, you are shadowing names here. Don't name your script `time.py`.

Comment: The problem is that you named your script `time.py`, so when you import time, you are importing your own file rather than the time module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You named your script `time.py`. It relies on the builtin module `time`.

**Now, if you were the Python Interpreter, how would you tell the difference between your `time` script and the builtin one?** It can't! Instead, local files take precedence.

Simply rename your script to something else.

Comment: @MiaChen please click the check mark next to my answer and upvote it if you want to thank me :)

Comment: Yes, done! Thanks!

Comment: @MiaChen Thank you. :)